# What is this MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, identification, gpu

[image]

I can't find any replacement for this MOSFET. Is this a **ao e6936 or ao ga 7414?**

Comment: This [type](https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/427/sizf906bdt-2898257.pdf) could be a potential candidate. It was a few keystrokes away...

Comment: -1 because this question could easily have been answered with a web search on the case numbering.

Answer (score 2):

> *Is this a ao e6936 or ao ga 7414?*

It's most likely (although not certain) an [AOE6936](http://www.aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AOE6936.pdf): -

[image]

It's a dual MOSFET by the way if it is the device I believe it to be. So, count the pins, measure the dimensions, read up on the device markings and type of manufactured date code used by Alpha and Omega (it might match the GA7414 legend) and lastly, measure voltages on your unknown electronics to see if the AOE6936 is likely to be the part.

Comment: @saranshkumar what further information do you require from me (remembering that this is a question and answer site)?

Comment: @saranshkumar Check mfg product page for markings. http://www.aosmd.com/products/lv-mosfets/asymmetric/AOE6936

Comment: @saranshkumar that is an unrelated question to your original. If you want to know how to properly solder this device to the circuit board you should read the manufacturer's recommendations. Note that this site is not a talking-shop or forum; it's a Q and A site and, extending the remit of your original question is usually frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

To find a replacement as a component/design engineer,  knowing how to look up parts and where to find them in any quantity or alternates is a key skill to learn.

Here are some clues.

https://www.digipart.com/part/AOE6936

Comment: I learned that this part meets the exemption criteria for ROHS3 high-temperature lead solder as no drop-in lead-free replacement exists.  http://www.aosmd.com/media/EnvironmentalComplianceStatement.pdf